# How to split the column values separated with | and group them in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a column with values like this:

```
Description
-----------
1|123
1|124
1|125
2|356
2|746
```

I need to return this as a table with two columns:

```
Id    Description
-----------------
1     123,124,125
2     356,746
```

Please can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: What have **you tried** so far? We'll be glad to lend a helping hand - but we won't just write the whole code for you - SO is a Q&A site - not a code-writing service after all !

Comment: Neither of these forms are particularly "healthy". Each column should contain (for each row) a *single* scalar value. Not pipe-separated nor comma-separated repeating values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function :

```
  Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter          varchar(20))
 RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
 value varchar(8000)  
)
 AS
 BEGIN

 DECLARE @index int
 SET @index = -1

   WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
    BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
      IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
  BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
      BREAK 
  END 
IF (@index > 1) 
  BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
    SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
  END 
ELSE
  SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
END
  RETURN
   END
```

then pass your string parameter and separator in your case it will be |